# Help me name this property (C#)

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

Imagine I created this class:

```
 public class ColoredPolygon
 {
     public Point[] Vertices { get; set; }
     public Brush Brush { get; set; }
 }
```

Inside Visual Studio isn't difficult to see which "Brush" is the class and which is the property. But something tells me that is not a best practice to name a property after its class. How would you name this property?

**Update** One more question about naming: How do you name Arrays? With the plural or with singular?

Comment: Arrays -> Plural;   Guitars[] signifies a collection of guitars; more intuitive

Comment: @Dreas Your syntax is unclear, you mean "Guitar[] guitars".

Comment: @Trillian: yes, u're right; it should be Guitar[] guitars;  Sorry for the typo in the first comment

Comment: I think it might be difficult to read when you start using static members of the class Brush inside a method of your class ColoredPolygon. 

Before I never worried about it. But since the auto properties, there is no lower case variable brush that you use inside ColoredPolygon. Now when I define Brush Brush then intellisense will list 2 options for the function equals (one static one not). When you choose the static one "Brush" will become colored, so that should indicate it. But it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would call it `Brush`. The [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) actually says:

> Consider giving a property the same
>   name as its type

(in the [section about naming Type members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)). The text following the statement suggests to do this for properties that are of Enum types, but you can find plenty of examples of this approach for other types of objects in the .NET framework, for instance the `Brush` and `Color` properties of the `Pen` class.

Nothing to worry about, if `Brush` is a descriptive name for your property you should use that name, especially since it would even follow the naming pattern that you can see within the framework.

Answer (score 5):

FillBrush is a good, descriptive name (and I've upvoted) but, honestly, don't worry about it until it actually becomes a real problem.  In your case, it may not be the best name, but if it **were** the best name, I'd keep it until the context dictated otherwise.  I have a few examples where the name of the class and the property is the same, but since the property usually is qualified by a variable name (or `this.`), I don't worry too much about it.

I find the following pretty readable:

```
var poly = new ColoredPolygon();
poly.Brush = Brushes.Green;
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `FillBrush`?

Comment: Good Inspiration. I changed to Filling.

Comment: "Filling" sounds like it belongs inside a donut.  FillBrush is a better name than Filling.

Answer (score 0):

As well as `FillBrush`, mentioned in another answer, you might consider adding a way to set just the fill `Color`, so that the user won't have to construct a brush just to set a solid color fill.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Fredrik's suggestion (Brush Brush) and also MS's naming suggestions, you may *consider* giving a property the same name as its type, but you cannot always do it. If for example you have a public enum called `Something` defined in a class, then that class cannot also have a property called `Something`.

You can have a property called `Brush`, presumably because `Brush` is defined in a different namespace/class and the compiler is then smart enough to figure out which `Brush` you mean.